# bokeh - get list of active legend items

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, bokeh

In bokeh, I have a line plot consisting of over 20 lines (or 'types'). I am using `legend.click_policy='hide'` to manage the figure space. I also want to add `LabelSet` to the plot however, but I am having trouble only displaying labels for legend items which are active. I am thinking of creating a checkbox to toggle datalabels for active legend items on / off. Here is the basic from of my code thus far:

```
from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, HoverTool,CategoricalColorMapper, 
    Legend, LabelSet)
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import (Button, CheckboxGroup)

#plot setup 
p = figure( plot_width=1400, plot_height=750, x_range=quarters)

legend_items=[]
for type, color in sorted(zip(types, itertools.cycle(Category20_16))): 
    c=p.line(dfqtr["x"][dfqtr["type"]==str(type)], dfqtr["y"][dfqtr["type"]==str(type)], color=color)
    c.visible=False
    legend_items.append((type,[c]))

legend=Legend(items=legend_items, location=(0,-100))
legend.click_policy='hide'

#checkbox setup
def data_labels():
    labelsrc= ColumnDataSource(data=dfqtr.loc[dfqtr['TYPE'] == str("ACTIVE_LEGEND ITEMS")]) 
####how to determine which legend items are active?#####
    labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='y', source=labelsrc, level='glyph',render_mode='canvas')
    p.add_layouts(labels)

chk_box=CheckboxGroup(labels=["Show Labels"])
chk_box.on_click(data_labels)

#layout
layout=layout([p_title],[p], [chk_box,slider,button],[data_table])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is stored on the glyph renderer, i.e. the `c` returned by `p.line`. You'll probably want to iterate over `legend.items` since each `LegendItem` has a reference to one of the renderers. You will have to look at

```
renderer.visible
```

or

```
renderer.muted
```

depending on whether the legend policy is to hide completely, or just to mute.

More information about the structure of things:

```
plot.legend  # a list of Legend objects

# most plots only have a single legend, so you probably want:
plot.legend[0].items # a list of LegendItem objects

# Each LegendItem has a 'label' property and a 'renderers` property
for item in legend[0].items:
    item.label # possibly a dict like: {'value': 'foo'}
    item.renderers # a list of GlyphRenderer objects
```

It is the `GlyphRenderer` objects that have the `muted` and `visible` properties you can inspect.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm a bit stuck still on the function. I passed the function to the check box callback via `chk_box.on_click(data_labels(legend_items))`. Then for `def data_labels(legend):` I am iterating through the legend via `for item in legend`.. but how can I check whether they are visible? `item.visible` returns `tuple object has no attribute 'visible'`. is this where `c` come in? Many thanks

Comment: One of the items in the tuple is a list of renderers, which are what have the visible property

Comment: each tuple element in `legend_items` look something like `('My Label 1',GlyphRenderer(id='1234',...))`. Checking `GlyphRenderer.visible` via `for tupl in legend_items:` then `if tupl[1].visible:` yields `AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'visible'`. Have I veered completely off course?

Comment: ok im going somewhere with this: `for item in legend.item` and `if item.renderers[0]`

Comment: I've added more information about the structure of the data.